# How to reRender one cell @ rich:dataTable

Tags: richfaces

I am currently using a rich:dataTable to display some information from the database. I would like to re-render a single cell from that table, as soon as a user clicks on a specific link. My problem is that I don't know where to get the full ID (tableId:consecutiveNumber:cellId) from the cell? If i just use the cellId in the reRender attribute, it does not work.

As a 'workaround' I just re-render the full table, but I would like to avoid that, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the row id via ajaxKeys attribute on rich:dataTable and which component inside the row via standard reRender.  Something like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton reRender="di2"/>
<rich:dataTable ajaxKeys="#{bean.rows}">
  <rich:column>
    <h:outputText id="di2"/>
  </rich:column>

</rich:dataTable>
```